# Ajax preloader doesn't stop when finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using AJAX in jQuery and because I want to display notification to the user while loading items I have used `ajaxStart()` and `ajaxComplete()`.

The problem is when it loads the first time the notification doesn't get removed.

```
function runAjax(tags, contracts, educations, towns) {
    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        $("#wait").css("display", "block");
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
        $("#wait").css("display", "none");
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.doyleia.com/anazitisi-ergasias?' + tags + '&' + contracts + '&' + educations + '&' + towns,
    }).done(function(data) {
        // create jquery object from response
        var $html = $(data);
        //hide within that object
        $html.find('.form-for-hide').hide();
        $html.find('p.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
        // insert the object
        $('div.load-jobs').html($html);
    });
}
```

you can see the problem [here](http://www.doyleia.com/anazitisi-ergasias).

Comment: Better use .always() to just hide the loader. And all logic should stay at done()

Comment: There's an error with select2 plugin on your site, that is causing it to not work.